# How to make 3 dimensional array for CNN input python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, conv-neural-network, mfcc

I am trying to learn cnn network to recognize emotion in speech. For this I am using the mel-ceptral coefficients (mfcc) which represent each audio file as two dimensional array (number of frames * number of mfcc coefficients). I want to have a 3-dimentional array as an input for my cnn convolution layer, where 3rd dimension is number of audio files. How can i get such array?

```
for i in range(len(audio_list)):
        (rate,sig) = wav.read(source_folder + audio_list[i])
        inputs = mfcc(sig, rate, nfft=1300)
        # Transform in 3D array
        train_inputs[i] = (np.asarray(inputs[np.newaxis, :]))
```

Comment: Post also what else you've tried and its corresponding tracebacks.

Answer (score 0):

If your `inputs` is a list convert it to numpy array, by `np.array(inputs)`

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
train_inputs[i] = inputs.reshape((1,inputs.shape[0],inputs.shape[1]))
```

This line is basically putting the entire matrix into another matrix, giving it one more dimension.